# Show sub categories where location has jobs

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories, category-group, child-categories

I have a category group that's attached to several channels, including the jobs channel.

This isn't the way I'd have configured this initially but never mind.

I have 2 parent categories USA & Europe and then cities as sub categories. I want to show the cities and the jobs in those cities.

Not all cities have jobs and right now, using GWCategories, I'm spitting out cities where there are no jobs.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="jobs" last_only="yes" cat_id="13" show_empty="no"}
{cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Gives me all cities, irrespective of whether they have jobs or not.

Comment: Have you tried adding the entry_id="" parameter to the gw cats tag?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the status parameter. Several entries with 'closed' status.

Code that works is

```
{exp:gwcode_categories 
  status="open" 
  channel="jobs" 
  show_empty="no" 
  last_only="yes"
  cat_id="19"
}

  {cat_name}
  {embed="careers/.jobs" cat_id="{cat_id}"}

{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```